# Computing $ \sum_{k\ge2}k(1-p)^{k-2}$

Tags: power-series

Computing $\displaystyle \sum_{k\ge2}k(1-p)^{k-2}$, $p\in ]0,\space1[$

[WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%28k%2a%281-p%29%5E%28k-2%29,%202,%20infinity%29) says it is $\cfrac {p+1}{p^2}$ but I couldn't get that value but anyway here is what I did:

$$\displaystyle \sum_{k\ge2}k(1-p)^{k-2} = (1-p)^{-1}\sum_{k\ge2}k(1-p)^{k-1} = (1-p)^{-1} \left (-\sum_{k\ge1}(1-p)^{k} \right)'= (1-p)^{-1} \left (-\cfrac {1-p}{p}\right)' = (1-p)^{-1} \left (1-p^{-1}\right)'=(1-p)^{-1} p^{2} = \cfrac 1{p^2(1-p)}$$

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong or is WolframAlpha wrong on this one?

Comment: You have to derive wrt to $(1-p)$, not $p$!

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio what?

Comment: @Jack: No, you don’t; the problem is that F'Ola changed the summation from $\sum_{k\ge 2}$ to $\sum_{k\ge 1}$ when it should have remained $\sum_{k\ge 2}$. The method is fine.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott But I thought one **has** to change it when applying derivation or integration?

Comment: Whether you have to shift it or not depends on how you’ve written the general term inside the summations. When in doubt, write out the first two or three terms in each summation to make sure that they match up properly. I said a bit about this in my answer; see if it helps.

Comment: I just did that and realized how stupid I've been. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shifted the index when you should not have done so:

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k\ge 2}k(1-p)^{k-1}&=-\left(\sum_{k\ge 2}(1-p)^k\right)'\\
&=-\left(\frac{(1-p)^2}p\right)'\\
&=\frac{(1-p)^2+2p(1-p)}{p^2}\\
&=\frac{1-p^2}{p^2}\\
&=\frac{(1-p)(1+p)}{p^2}\;.
\end{align*}$$

You had $-\left(\sum_{k\ge 1}(1-p)^k\right)'$, but if you write out the first couple of terms, you’ll see that this gives you a term that isn’t present in the original summation: the $k=1$ term, after differentiation, is $-1\cdot(1-p)^0(-1)=1$, while $\sum_{k\ge 2}k(1-p)^{k-1}$ has no constant term.

If you keep the right range of indices, you get

$$(1-p)^{-1}\cdot\frac{(1-p)(1+p)}{p^2}=\frac{1+p}{p^2}\;,$$ just as Wolfram|Alpha does.

By the way, you could reduce the chance of making computational errors by letting $q=1-p$ and working with $q$; dealing with $\sum_{k\ge 2}kq^{k-1}$ is easier than dealing with $\sum_{k\ge 2}k(1-p)^{k-1}$, especially when you get to the differentiations.

Answer (score 3):

$$f(x):=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}\,\,\,,\,\,|x|<1\Longrightarrow$$

$$\Longrightarrow f'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1}=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}\Longrightarrow $$

$$\Longrightarrow \frac{1}{x(1-x)^2}-\frac{1}{x}=\sum_{n=2}^\infty nx^{n-2}$$

so substituting $\,x=1-p\,$ (why can we?), we get

$$\frac{1}{p^2(1-p)}-\frac{1}{1-p}=\sum_{n=2}^\infty n(1-p)^{n-2} $$

And since

$$\frac{1}{p^2(1-p)}-\frac{1}{1-p}=\frac{1+p}{p^2}$$

we're then done.